# How to keep Bootstrap columns centred when viewed on mobile or notepad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have six simple Bootstrap columns that look good on the desktop, nicely centred horizontally, but when the browser is shrunk, or the page is viewed on a notepad or a mobile the columns are not centred horizontally any more but closer to the left side than to the right.

My code, and the problem, can be seen at: http://www.bootply.com/tdBAEUUgMI#

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your columns are perfectly centered. Their contents, however, are closer to the left side because they have style `float:left;`. So I suggest to remove this style. Replace this:

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-1 text-center">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <div>ONE</div>
        <div class="text-left">Nightlife</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this:

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-1 text-center">
    <div>
        <div>ONE</div>
        <div>Nightlife</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in all your columns and you should be done. Check the **[demo](http://www.bootply.com/SBJBSfTa0c#)**.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that but clearly I hadn't!